# VS 2008 remote debugger for x64 crashes about 60% of the time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

The VS 2008 remote debugger for x64 crashes about 60% of the time. The rest of the time it works great. Has anyone encountered or fixed this?
I'm not sure what other details I could provide other than I'm attempting to debug a .NET 3.5 Service running on a remote machine with Windows Server 2008 x64 for an OS.

This is what happens:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: msvsmon.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.30729.1
  Application Timestamp:    488f0767
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6002.18005
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49e0421d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000048d50
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: b084
  Additional Information 2: 5ce230d68edf4fcfc83c96b6e817ab3d
  Additional Information 3: b116
  Additional Information 4: bea134da63d7eb14d227ee108a03059a
```

Comment: might need more information.....

Comment: You'll have to take this to Microsoft Support.  Test on a virgin machine before you spend the money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if I disable everything but 'Managed Code' when attaching the debugger, the problem goes away.
Weird, but debugging managed code is all I wanted, so good enough for me.

Comment: Please, can you explain what exactly you disable? Any process of the remote server?